# Sample from a dataset to generate a subset that has similar properties to another dataset

Tags: r, subsampling

Let's say I have a large dataset of numeric values:

```
big_dataset = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 20, sd = 10)
```

I want to pull out a subset of observations from `big_dataset` that have similar values (within 5 units) to those in an existing and independent dataset:

```
independent_dataset = runif(n = 20, min = 0, max = 100)
```

That way both my newly made subset and `independent_dataset` are comparable. What's a good way to do this?

All I can come up with is an apply loop that searches iteratively for something close to each value in `independent_dataset` but I thought there might be a more elegant way...

Comment: There are many ways to code it, but however you do in you're going to need to compare values in the big data to those in the small data and pick values where the difference is small. If the big data is very big, you could increase efficiency by stopping the search as soon as you find a suitable value - this is hard to do in a vectorized approach so it doesn't work well in R, it would be better to code it in Rcpp. But if you want *the closest* value then you will need to check every point.

Comment: Please specify on *that have similar values (within 5 units)*. How is similiarity measured?

Comment: @Friede, similarity is defined as the two values being <= 5 apart.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding (+1) for your approach. Possible downside: The sample from `big_dataset` is always the same size as `independent_dataset` unless I'm missing something

Comment: Correct. Always the same length.

Comment: Is this what you want, @CephBirk

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try

```
big_dataset[max.col(-abs(outer(independent_dataset, big_dataset, `-`)))]
```

Comment: This works great but has the downside of possibly pulling the same value from big_dataset multiple times. I suppose any version that avoids previous pulls will have to be some sort of loop?

Comment: @CephBirk yes, the repeated draws is an issue for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `radius` search type and distance in the `RANN::nn2`:

```
apply(
  RANN::nn2(
    big_dataset,
    independent_dataset,
    length(big_dataset),
    searchtype = "radius",
    radius = 5
  )[[1]], 1, \(x) x[x != 0L]
)
```

Each element of the `big_similar` list will contain the values within 5 of the corresponding value in `independent_dataset`.

---

Another option, using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
i <- seq_along(independent_dataset)
dt <- data.table(
  v = c(independent_dataset - 5, big_dataset, independent_dataset + 5),
  i = c(i, integer(length(big_dataset)), i)
)
setorder(dt, v)[,j := .I]
setorder(dt[i != 0L
  , {
    r <- j
    .(vInd = independent_dataset[i], vBig = .(dt[r[1]:r[2]][i == 0L, v]))
  }, i
], i)[,i := NULL][]
#>         vInd                                                      vBig
#>  1: 39.05293 34.40019,34.42997,34.48287,34.94542,35.02730,35.05976,...
#>  2: 52.24089                                48.30979,50.67553,56.02477
#>  3: 85.36959                                                          
#>  4: 59.40061                                                  56.02477
#>  5: 10.30652 5.344624,5.365774,5.466547,5.533230,5.787786,5.817441,...
#>  6: 96.68002                                                          
#>  7: 39.81330 34.94542,35.02730,35.05976,35.67742,35.72234,35.75184,...
#>  8: 70.32747                                                          
#>  9: 79.96525                                                          
#> 10: 42.92298 37.98900,38.30225,38.40954,38.82281,38.88412,39.10196,...
#> 11: 42.01954 37.24025,37.34674,37.50477,37.62358,37.69603,37.75336,...
#> 12: 40.99353 36.70751,36.91647,36.92494,37.24025,37.34674,37.50477,...
#> 13: 36.90136 32.14804,32.19208,32.22644,32.38380,32.43632,32.57504,...
#> 14: 58.42638                                                  56.02477
#> 15: 75.50957                                                          
#> 16: 39.57639 34.94542,35.02730,35.05976,35.67742,35.72234,35.75184,...
#> 17: 81.14091                                                          
#> 18: 93.58480                                                          
#> 19: 42.86739 37.98900,38.30225,38.40954,38.82281,38.88412,39.10196,...
#> 20: 63.53754
```